# Automatic formula calculation in excel

Tags: mysql, excel, excel-formula

I have a small query regarding automatic formula value calculation in excel. 
In my project I will be having 200 questions and corresponding 200 answers( numerical values of 10,20 and 30). Those questions and answers are obtained from webpages and all the questions and answers are stored in my sql database. I will collect the answers that are posted in mysql database to excel with the help of mysql add-in.

[image]
 My question is I have some formulas 
given in my excel sheet ex:mean(C204), STDEV(C205), final risk( my own formula F209)
[image]

I want the formulas to automatically calculate the formula values whenever I import the 
data from mysql. Is it possible in excel if not is there any alternative? Please help!

Comment: Please always include the pictures directly in your post rather than adding them in a link.

Comment: @vbaPete, posting the pictures themselves is a privilege you don't earn until you are at 50 points... or 100... I can't remember.

Comment: Good to know, thanks @JNevill

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a stab in the dark since I'm not at all familiar with the add in or how it operates. It seems odd that it would import data and not allow a `application.calculate` event to take place after import.

Perhaps... you can run the `application.calculate` method on worksheet change. In your VBE, double click the worksheet upon which the mysql data is dropped. Then add this code to that worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

There's fairly good chance that the add in also snuffs events by setting `application.enableEvents = false` which means this won't work, but... it's worth a shot.